# Convergence of best response dynamics to pure Nash equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, economics, nash-equilibrium

In a 2 player game with a **unique pure nash equilibrium (PNE)**, what are the conditions for the best response dynamics to converge to this PNE? Both players have concave and continuous utility functions and the best response functions are linear. I see in my simulations that no matter where I start, the iterated best response dynamics always finds the Nash Equilibrium, but is there a generalization of this and a theorem you can direct me to? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The paper you're after is Milgrom & Roberts (1990) Econometrica
'[Rationalizability, Learning, and Equilibrium in Games with Strategic Complementarities](http://sites-final.uclouvain.be/econ/DW/DOCTORALWS2004/bruno/Rabat/milgrom%20roberts%201990.pdf)'.

In particular, supermodular games, as defined in the paper, are a broad class of games in which iterated best-response dynamics converge to (pure strategy) Nash equilibrium (though these need not be unique).  One sometimes sees this in simple oligopoly models where best-replies happen to be contractions; this is, of course, far from necessary though as the linked paper illustrates.

In particular, a simple two-player case when best replies converge is given by when:

1. Each agent's strategy space is a compact interval in $\mathbb{R}$.
2. Payoff functions for each player are twice continuously differentiable.
3. The cross derivatives of the payoff functions are positive.

For a significant step up in generality see Theorem 4 in particular.

Comment: Milgrom and Roberts (1990) is great, but surely there’s a much larger literature to refer to regarding equilibrium dynamics? For one thing, I know Hart has a number of papers on this that, IIRC, speak more directly to the OP’s question.